# Sencha Touch error: object has no method getShowInLegend

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, sencha-touch, sencha-charts

Sencha Touch 2.3.1
Cmd: 4.0.X.X

My Sencha Touch Charts app throws this error when it tries to draw charts:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getShowInLegend'   AbstractChart.js?_dc=1395914109534:649
>   Ext.define.refreshLegendStore AbstractChart.js?_dc=1395914109534:649
>   Ext.define.updateSeries AbstractChart.js?_dc=1395914109534:877
>   setter sencha-touch-all-debug.js:5491
>   Base.implement.initConfig sencha-touch-all-debug.js:4920
>   Ext.define.constructor sencha-touch-all-debug.js:22651
>   Base.implement.callParent sencha-touch-all-debug.js:4656
>   Ext.define.constructor sencha-touch-all-debug.js:32375
>   Base.implement.callSuper sencha-touch-all-debug.js:4735
>   Ext.define.constructor Component.js?_dc=1395914109519:100
>   Base.implement.callSuper sencha-touch-all-debug.js:4735
>   Ext.define.constructor AbstractChart.js?_dc=1395914109534:626
>   Class sencha-touch-all-debug.js:5208
>   (anonymous function) VM14212:3
>   Ext.ClassManager.instantiate sencha-touch-all-debug.js:6936
>   Ext.ClassManager.instantiateByAlias sencha-touch-all-debug.js:6848
>   Ext.apply.factory sencha-touch-all-debug.js:9980
>   Ext.define.factoryItem sencha-touch-all-debug.js:32637
>   Ext.define.add sencha-touch-all-debug.js:32714
>   Ext.define.applyItems sencha-touch-all-debug.js:32538
>   setter sencha-touch-all-debug.js:5482
>   (anonymous function) sencha-touch-all-debug.js:5516
>   Ext.define.applyActiveItem sencha-touch-all-debug.js:33208
>   (anonymous function) sencha-touch-all-debug.js:16565
>   Base.implement.initConfig sencha-touch-all-debug.js:4920
>   Ext.define.constructor sencha-touch-all-debug.js:22651
>   Base.implement.callParent sencha-touch-all-debug.js:4656
>   Ext.define.constructor sencha-touch-all-debug.js:32375
>   Class sencha-touch-all-debug.js:5208
>   (anonymous function) VM14212:3
>   Ext.ClassManager.instantiate sencha-touch-all-debug.js:6936
>   Ext.ClassManager.instantiateByAlias sencha-touch-all-debug.js:6848
>   Ext.apply.factory sencha-touch-all-debug.js:9980
>   Ext.define.factoryItemWithDefaults sencha-touch-all-debug.js:32683
>   Ext.define.add sencha-touch-all-debug.js:32707
>   Ext.define.applyItems sencha-touch-all-debug.js:32538
>   setter sencha-touch-all-debug.js:5482
>   (anonymous function) sencha-touch-all-debug.js:5516
>   Ext.define.applyActiveItem sencha-touch-all-debug.js:33208
>   Base.implement.callParent sencha-touch-all-debug.js:4656
>   Ext.define.applyActiveItem sencha-touch-all-debug.js:46269
>   (anonymous function) sencha-touch-all-debug.js:16565
>   Base.implement.initConfig sencha-touch-all-debug.js:4920
>   Ext.define.constructor sencha-touch-all-debug.js:22651
>   Base.implement.callParent sencha-touch-all-debug.js:4656
>   Ext.define.constructor sencha-touch-all-debug.js:32375
>   Class sencha-touch-all-debug.js:5208
>   (anonymous function) VM14212:3
>   Ext.ClassManager.instantiate sencha-touch-all-debug.js:6936
>   Ext.ClassManager.instantiateByAlias sencha-touch-all-debug.js:6848
>   Ext.apply.factory sencha-touch-all-debug.js:9980
>   Ext.define.factoryItem sencha-touch-all-debug.js:32637
>   Ext.define.add sencha-touch-all-debug.js:32714
>   doCharts doCharts.js:394
>   Ext.Ajax.request.success standardFunctions.js:166
>   Ext.apply.callback sencha-touch-all-debug.js:10268
>   Ext.define.onComplete sencha-touch-all-debug.js:35765
>   Ext.define.onStateChange sencha-touch-all-debug.js:35709
>   (anonymous function)

The charts are rendered to this view:

```
Ext.define('dashboards.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    requires: [
        'Ext.chart.*',
        'Ext.draw.sprite.Sector',
        'Ext.chart.Chart', 
        'Ext.chart.series.Column',
        'Ext.chart.AbstractChart',
        'Ext.chart.SpaceFillingChart',
        'Ext.dataview.component.Container',
        'Ext.chart.series.Series',
        'Ext.chart.series.Gauge',
        'Ext.carousel.Indicator',
        'Ext.carousel.Infinite',
        'Ext.carousel.Item',
        'Ext.carousel.Carousel',
        'Ext.fx.easing.EaseOut',
        'Ext.util.TranslatableGroup',
        'Ext.chart.series.Cartesian',
        'Ext.chart.series.Area',
        'Ext.chart.Label',
        'Ext.chart.Highlight',
        'Ext.chart.Callout',
        'Ext.chart.Transformable',
        'Ext.chart.series.ItemEvents',
        'Ext.chart.theme.Style',
        'Ext.draw.Color', 
        'Ext.chart.series.Bar',
        'Ext.chart.series.Column',
        'Ext.chart.axis.Gauge',
        'Ext.chart.theme.Base',
        'Ext.chart.theme.Base',
        'Ext.chart.theme.TitleStyle',
        'Ext.chart.theme.GridStyle',
        'Ext.chart.Toolbar',
        'Ext.chart.legend.View',
        'Ext.chart.Legend',
        'Ext.chart.axis.Numeric',
        'Ext.chart.axis.Category',
        'Ext.draw.Surface',
        'Ext.draw.Draw',
        'Ext.draw.Matrix',
        'Ext.draw.engine.Canvas',
        'Ext.draw.CompositeSprite',
        'Ext.fx.Frame',
        'Ext.draw.Sprite',
        'Ext.fx.Sprite',
        'Ext.draw.sprite.Sector',
        'Ext.draw.sprite.Rect',
        'Ext.chart.interactions.Abstract',
        'Ext.chart.axis.Axis',
        'Ext.chart.axis.Abstract',
        'Ext.util.SizeMonitor',
        'Ext.chart.grid.HorizontalGrid','Ext.chart.grid.VerticalGrid','Ext.draw.fx.TimingFunctions','Ext.Container','Ext.TitleBar','Ext.data.Store','Ext.data.StoreManager'
        ],
    alias: 'widget.mainview',
    id: 'mainpage',
    getSlideLeftTransition: function () {
        return { type: 'slide', direction: 'left' };
    },

    getSlideRightTransition: function () {
        return { type: 'slide', direction: 'right' };
    },
    config: {
        layout: {
            type: 'fit'
        },
        items: [
            {
                 xtype : 'container',
                 flex: 1,
                 id: 'introtext',
                 html: '<p>Please select from your dashboards above</p>'
            },
            {
                 xtype : 'selectfield',
                 store : companiesStore2,
                 name : 'companies',
                 queryMode: 'local',
                 id : 'companiesSelect',
                    itemId: 'companySelect',
                    valueField : 'companyname',
                    displayField : 'companyname',
                    style: 'overflow:hidden',
                    listeners: {
                        change: function(field,value) {
                            getStats(value)
                        }
                    }   
              },

              {
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    docked: 'bottom',
                    id: 'bumtoolbar',
                    items: []
                },
                {
                layout: {
                    pack: 'end'
                },
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                id: 'titlebartop',
                title: 'axisfirst Dashboards',

                docked: 'top',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Log Off',
                        itemId: 'logOffButton2',
                        id: 'logOffButton2',
                        align: 'right',
                        cls: 'logoffBtn',
                        scope: this,
                        listeners: {                                
                            tap: function() {
                                Ext.Msg.confirm("Log out", "Are you sure you want to logout?", function(btn) {
                                if (btn === 'yes') {
                                    logout();
                                    //Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem({ xtype: loginview });

                                  } else {
                                    return false;
                                  }
                                }, this);

                            }                           
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }]
    }


});
```

The chart is added using a separate .js file. The code looks like this:

```
var chartgx = {
                                    cls: 'thegauge',
                                    itemId: 'gauge'+tt2,
                                    xtype: 'chart',
                                    shadow: true,
                                    store: gaugeStore,
                                    width : 'auto',
                                    animate: true,
                                    insetPadding: 50,
                                    axes: [{
                                        type: 'gauge',
                                        position: 'gauge',
                                        minimum: 0,
                                        maximum: gaugemax,
                                        steps: 10,
                                        margin: 10,
                                        direction: 'right'
                                    }],
                                    series: [{
                                        showInLegend: false,
                                        type: 'gauge',
                                        position: 'gauge',
                                        minimum: 0,
                                        maximum: gaugemax,
                                        steps: 10,
                                        margin: 10,
                                        angleField: 'CurrentValue',
                                        donut: 30,
                                        colorSet:[gaugeColor,'#e1e1e1']

                                    }]

                                };


                                var gaugeText = '<p class="gaugetitle">' + gaugeTitle + ': ' + currentValue + '</p>';
                                var chartgx2 = Ext.Container({
                                        xtype : 'container',
                                        flex: 1,
                                        layout: 'fit',
                                        cls: 'gaugeContainer',
                                        needle: true,
                                        items: chartgx, 
                                        html: gaugeText
                                   });
                                  if (gaugeTitle !== '') {
                                      allcharts.push(chartgx2);
                                  }
```

I have looked at AbstractChart.js and, sure enough, it is calling the function. I have searched my entire directory (inc /app and /src) but cannot find the function.

I have updated all files that 'Ext.chart.AbstractChart' requires and extends, but still get the error.

Can someone please tell me which class the function belongs to, so I can update from docs.sencha.com, or, alternatively, tell me how to correct this error.

Comment: Provide the code of your chart view.

Comment: @SujataChanda: more code added

Comment: @SujataChanda: via a separate file. Now added to this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

About your question, your "series" is defined on [AbstractChart](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/source/AbstractChart.html). Your chart extends AbstractChart so you dont need to add the require of it (AbstractChart). The method getSeries is generated by the sencha-touch core. All fields of a object that extends Ext.base has the get[MyField] and set[MyField].

The error is happing on [this](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/source/AbstractChart.html#Ext-chart-AbstractChart-method-refreshLegendStore) function. When it trys to getShowInLegend. But each item of Series has the method getShowInLegend, you can confirm looking [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/source/Series.html#Ext-chart-series-Series) on `showInLegend: true,` line.

Like I said in the first line, all objects that extends Ext.base have the get[MyField] method and [Ext-chart-series-Series](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.chart.series.Series) extends to Ext.base.

With this informations the problem is probably some misunderstanding on building the chart. But we dont have enogh information of how your chartgx is created. Have you used the Ext.create?